# Select the preceding sibling of an element in CSS using selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to select the above element of an element in CSS using selectors

```
<li class="content">One</li>
<li class="content">Two</li>
<li class="content">Three</li>
<li class="no-content">First</li>
<li class="content">Four</li>
<li class="content">Five</li>
<li class="content">Six</li>
```

Here I want to use the class `no-content`, so that I can get its above element `<li class="content">Three</li>`,  using CSS selector.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's possible yet. Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector Edit: If JS is an option it's obviously quite easy: `$('li.no-content').prev().addClass('prev')`

Comment: Rather than “above”, the term for the `<li>` before `<li class="no-content">` is “preceding sibling”.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is not possible with pure CSS...

Comment: 2017 - this is possible, see this fiddle I made. https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/cj55y33p/3/

Comment: @maxshuty your fiddle demonstrates the general sibling combinator, only finding siblings listed after the target! In fact, if you take out all the .top css (including the ~s you have used) the fiddle works the same! You have over complicated a wrong answer!

Comment: Using axe syntax, the selector `.no-content ? .content` would select `<li class="content">Three</li>` in the example above. See: https://github.com/RouninMedia/axe

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking the same:- http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/4Y9D5/3/

you can select to bottom div but not select to top .

Comment: Please check [http://jsfiddle.net/4Y9D5/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/4Y9D5/2/), Here I am just add a class to above element, actually it is not possible, but need like...

Comment: Hi you are select to bottom div as like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/4Y9D5/3/

Comment: No, please check [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4Y9D5/2/) that I have already given. I need like that, but without adding the class to preceding sibling, I want to select the preceding sibling using selector **no-content**...

Comment: now check to this you may define .test backgroundcolor as like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/4Y9D5/8/

Comment: I can't write class `test` there, its only for you to understand what I need. Is it possible to select the test class node to be selected with the class `no-content`...