# Select all labels EXCEPT those preceding a checkbox or radio input

Tags: jquery

Given the following form, how do I select all labels EXCEPT those immediately preceding a checkbox or radio input.

```
<form>
<label>Select This Label</label><input type="text" />
<label>Select This Label</label><input type="email" />
<label>Select This Label Main checkbox group</label><br>
<label>NOT THIS LABEL!</label><input type="checkbox" />
<label>NOT THIS LABEL!</label><input type="radio" />
<label>Select this arbitrary label just hanging out here</label>
</form>
```

Goal: I'm trying to add a class to all labels except label 4 and 5.

EDIT: The selectors I've tried use the + and :not() operators in different places. So

```
$( form label +:not(input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox]) ~ label)
```

or

```
$( form label:not(+input[type=radio],+input[type=checkbox]) ~ label)
```

and such.

Edit 2* I have a need to do this COMPLETELY in the selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible just by using a selector

```
$('label').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).next().is('[type="radio"], [type="checkbox"]')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L9zbr/)

Comment: I have a need to do this COMPLETELY in the selector.

Comment: @GeoffreyOchsner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006282/select-the-preceding-sibling-of-an-element-in-css-using-selectors

Comment: Marked as solution because it doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("form").find("label").each(function(){
    if(!($(this).next().is("input[type='radio']") || ($(this).next().is("input[type='checkbox']")))){
        $(this).addClass("someclass");
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hNn2p/)

Comment: I have a need to do this COMPLETELY in the selector.

Comment: "I have a need to do this COMPLETELY in the selector." Why?

Comment: Will the classic parent answer of "because I said so" suffice?