# Apply CSS to object, unless followed by paragraph

Tags: css

I was wondering how I could apply CSS to an `h2`, except when it's directly followed by a `paragraph`. In that case, apply the CSS to the `paragraph`.

I've got a few sections, each with it's own title. However, sometimes it's followed by a subtitle. I'm applying a bottom margin to each title, but if there is a subtitle, there shouldn't be a margin between. In that case that bottom margin should be applied to the paragraph beneath the h2.

But.. how do I fix that?

*I could give each h2 with a subtitle a class with "gotSubtitle" so I can keep them apart, but that's not the 'smooth' way to do this.*

Comment: There isn't a parent selector in css, which is what you'd need. javascript would be your best bet

Comment: Actually, using classes to style certain elements and not others is *in fact* the smooth and intended way to achieve that kind of behavior. That's the whole point of classes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just did it.

```css
article h2:not(.gotsubtitle){
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <h2 class='gotsubtitle'>Oi</h2>
    <p>Test</p>
</article>

<article>
    <h2>Oi</h2>
</article>
```

Added the class and the `:not` selector. ;)
Not too *smooth*, but... Is what we can do with pure CSS.

### Another possibility:

With jQuery...

```js
$('article').has('p').addClass('title');
```

```css
article.title h2{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
        <h2>Oi</h2>
        <p>Test</p>
    </article>

    <article>
        <h2>Oi</h2>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work:

```
h2.gotSubTitle{
/*apply CSS to an h2*/
}
p + h2.gotSubtitle{
/*apply CSS to an h2 which is directly followed by a paragraph*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `class="..."` to each element would sure work, but I think the easiest (and still clean) solution would be to pack both the `h2` and the `paragraph` into a `div` and apply the bottom margin to the div. No condition checking and it should work just as well.

And as [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006282/select-the-preceding-sibling-of-an-element-in-css-using-selectors) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237143/css-select-previous-sibling), there is an [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), but you can't select **preceding** elements with it, only **following** ones. However, it is possible to apply the bottom margin to **every** `h2` and then apply the same bottom margin and a **negative top margin** to the following `paragraph` element.
While to me that is everything but clean, it requires no modification of your html code.
Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7z3tyh3L/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var headerTag = document.querySelectorAll("h2");

for(var i = 0; i < headerTag.length; i++){
    var nextELement = headerTag[i].nextSibling.nextSibling;    
    if( (/P/).test(nextELement.tagName)) { 
        headerTag[i].classList.add("no")}
}
```

```css
h2{
    background:red
}
h2.no{
    background: none
}
```

```html
<section>
    <h2>header is following</h2>
    <h2>paragraph is following</h2>
    <p>i am a paragraph :-)</p>
</section>
```